# Binding wlan0 to eth0 in Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ethernet

When I type `ifconfig`,

I see `wlan0` and `eth0`.  I want to somehow bind these two together into one device.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like http://superuser.com/q/262329

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it, e.g. as root:

```
modprobe bonding
ifconfig bond0 up
ifenslave bond0 wlan0 eth0
```

then use your preferred method of getting an ip address and a default route for bond0

You can also include it in /etc/network/interfaces with proper config for bond0 and an if-post-up line for ifenslave

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after a [bridge](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge). It might [not work with your wireless card](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#It_doesn.27t_work_with_my_Wireless_card.21) (it depends on the model).