# Setup wireless network brigde interface (wlan0 with eth0) on linux

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, bridge, wireless-bridge, network-interface

I'm user of a **public wired network**. My machine gets ip (always the same) from it. Now I want to connect to this network my phone (which is registered device in network and can get its own ip address). So I need my computer to be the **bridge from eth0 to wlan0** more precisely.

I use archlinux OS.

```
                        [eth0] My computer [wlan0]
                  <---(wired)---'        `-,-'-(wirless)-,-'-> 
Public network (with Internet)                      My phone
```

How to make a bridge that allow my phone to connect 'directly'(bridged) to Public network?

PS. I'm **not** allowed to use NAT, and I'm not interested in buying any access points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you are trying to do [here](http://www.su-root.eu/computing/turn-your-linux-computer-in-a-wireless-access-point-using-hostapd) is the [guide](http://www.su-root.eu/computing/turn-your-linux-computer-in-a-wireless-access-point-using-hostapd) your wifi card needs to be capable of going into master mode if it cannot you will not be able to do what you are trying to. In that case you would need to get one that can but you should just get a router instead.

I would recommend getting a router either way as it creates a secure barrier between you and the **public** network you are on.

Comment: It not very public ;) it's only academic network. I'll try the tutorial.

Comment: When you don't have control over the other computers on the network it is public enough to be insecure :\

Comment: Unfortunately my wifi card doesn't support neither master nor repeater mode.

Comment: In that case I would try to setup your wifi card in ad-hoc with internet connection sharing to the ethernet port. Not sure how to do this but some googling and the archlinux wiki which is really nice should help you.

Comment: Is it possible without `NAT`?

Comment: If it can be setup this way it should work one interface has the connection and the other is sharing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look about `iptables`. It will allow you to program your arch for packet routing.

Use google, you won't have trouble to find this. Just do a forward of all packets from one net to the other.

BTW your computer should be able to set up an adhoc network to handle the wireless connections.

Comment: That should work but he wants the phone directly bridged to the public network.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was wondering if iptables could just forward all packets from wlan0 in monitoring mode. Basically the idea is to turn the PC into a AP repeater.

Comment: My wifi card **doesn't** support `repeater` mode. To forward packets with `iptables` I probably would have to use **NAT** which doesn't interest me.